# Running docker-compose with Rancher OS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, rancher

I am trying with  aws rancher os. I want to create and run a docker-compose file with the same rancher OS. When I am trying with Docker-compose up command I am getting the error 'not recognized docker-compose.

please anyone help me on this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RancherOS is a minimal installation of the Linux kernel, Docker daemon, and generally as little as possible else.  `docker-compose` is not part of the default console.

Depending on what you're trying to do you can create a RancherOS service with docker-compose syntax: https://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.2/en/system-services/adding-system-services/

Or run actual docker-compose from a container: `docker run docker/compose:1.10.0`

Or switch to one of the persistent consoles and install it locally: https://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.2/en/configuration/switching-consoles/

Comment: I seemed to need the -v to get anything to work properly, not sure why.

Answer (score 5):

Only to add another possibility to AXE Labs and Vincents suggestion:

create a file `/usr/bin/docker-compose` with the following content:

```
#/bin/bash

docker run \
  -ti --rm \
  -v $(pwd):$(pwd) \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -w $(pwd) \
  docker/compose \
  $@
```

and another `chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose`

now you can use commands like `docker-compose up` as if it where installed!

Answer (score 2):

Vincent's suggestion to use the compose container works, with some extra params:

```
$ cat > /tmp/docker-compose.yml << _EOF
> version: '3.0'
>
> services:
>
>   busybox:
>     image: busybox:latest
>     command: "/bin/sh -c 'sleep 30s'"
>
>   alpine:
>     image: alpine:latest
>     command: "/bin/sh -c 'sleep 60s'"
> _EOF
$ docker run -v /tmp:/tmp -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -w /tmp docker/compose:1.14.0 up -d
Creating network "tmp_default" with the default driver
Creating tmp_busybox_1 ...
Creating tmp_alpine_1 ...
Creating tmp_busybox_1
Creating tmp_alpine_1 ... done
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7f0eccacd100        alpine:latest       "/bin/sh -c 'sleep..."   2 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                            tmp_alpine_1
8f36a3cb1345        busybox:latest      "/bin/sh -c 'sleep..."   2 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                            tmp_busybox_1
```

This was in RancherOS v1.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [RancherOS console documentation](https://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.x/en/configuration/switching-consoles/#console-persistence), the following directories are persistent:

```bash
/home
/opt
/var/lib/docker
/var/lib/rancher
```

With that in mind, we can upload the binary to our `/home` directory and add it to our executable path.

--

To find the correct build, find the "machine hardware" architecture of your instance:

```bash
uname -m
# Example output: `x86_64`
```

Download the corresponding binary from the [releases page](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases) and upload it to your server *(using `scp`, `rsync`, etc..)*:

```bash
rsync --progress ./docker-compose-linux-x86_64 user@host:~/docker-compose-linux-x86_64
```

Login to your server and prepare the file:

```bash
# Create a `bin` directory to house our executables
mkdir ~/bin

# Move the file to the bin directory (renaming it in the process)
mv ~/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 ~/bin/docker-compose

# Make the file executable
chmod +x ~/bin/docker-compose
```

Assuming your shell is `bash` *(to confirm, run `echo $SHELL`)*, create a `.bash_profile` document with the following contents to add our new directory to our executable `PATH` variable:

```bash
[ -d "${HOME}/bin" ] && export PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/bin"
```